# nroot/unbrick Galaxy S2 SGH-T989

Tags: unbricking, unrooting

I am having problems trying to go to this screen

[image: This is the part I want to go]

but the process ends me up on this screen

[image: Ending part]

My process:

1. Turn off device
2. Hold power volume up and down until a vibration
3. Event: shows the end screen but not the warning screen

Can someone guide to get to the warning screen so I can connect directly of computer and access it by odin?

[Url of what I am trying to do](http://galaxys2root.com/t-mobile-galaxy-s2/how-to-unrootunbrick-to-ics-stock-on-t-mobile-galaxy-s2-sgh-t989/)

Answer (score 1):

When starting your phone in step 2 of your example, hold the `volume down` only. Once the warning screen appears, then press `volume up`.